# HTTP Digest authentication fails with Ajax requests

Tags: .htaccess

Apologies if this should be on ServerFault, please move/vote to move if necessary.

I have come across a problem with a `.htpasswd` file whereby

- Accessing a page normally requests a username and password as expected

  > I can then browse the site as expected and navigate through pages without authentication being requested on each page load.
- Accessing a page on the same server, same base URL, using the same protocol but using AJAX re-requests authentication.

  > If I then authenticate, the AJAX request is successful, but the authentication on the main browser window is no longer valid and therefore the next refresh requests authentication.

This only happens on one vhost of many on the server, all of which use the same `.htpasswd` file. The Request for authentication is in the global Apache config file, and not specific to a vhost.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthUserFile /var/www/private/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "My Private Directory"
    AuthType Basic
    <Limit GET POST>
        require valid-user
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

The `.htaccess` file in the only vhost in which it does not work is as follows. Nothing special which should affect it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/=$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

My question therefore is why do AJAX requests require a user to authenticate again?